# How do you walk from Windhelm to Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I walked from Whiterun to Windhelm by following the signs and checking the worldmap. My final destination was Winterhold, however. Once I got to Windhelm, I couldn't find any more signs that pointed what road to take to Winterhold. I looked on the world map, but the roads aren't clearly labeled there like they were in Oblivion. I couldn't see any part of the terrain that looked particularly passable or road-like.

I eventually took a carriage to Winterhold, but I would like to know what route I should be taking if I decide to walk there in the future. Where is the road to Winterhold?

Comment: Has anyone else had trouble keeping the names of these three straight? They all start with W and they all have 2 words in them. Pretty confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having problems with this too. From looking at the map I thought that I could travel along the coast to the east of Windhelm to get to Winterhold, but there is no path for that. You actually have to go west from Windhelm then North through a mountain pass. From there you'll end up along the coast east of Winterhold. There you'll start heading west till you get to Winterhold.

For a better picture you can look at [this map](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Map_%28Skyrim%29) from the Skyrim Wikia. It may be a spoiler if you'd rather explore it yourself.

Comment: I was able to find the passage you mentioned, but before reaching the top you encounter something like a fortress with a wizard, walking skeletons and something big made of ice (don't know the name of it)... Now I am at Winterhelm and I would like to take the carriage to Winterhold... where could I best take it from?

Comment: There is no city called Winterhelm. Do you mean Windhelm?

Comment: @Athena That should be its own question, not a comment on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Clairvoyance spell can be used to show you the way to your destination, even when wandering around the main map. It sometimes takes you a little out of the way but I've found it to be quite accurate.

Comment: One of the loading screen tips (I think?) mentions that Clairvoyance prioritizes player-placed markers over everything else.

Comment: I've had plenty of situations where it totally broke down for me.  It would tell me to go up a trail, only to point me back the way I came from after walking down it for a few steps, getting stuck in an endless loop.